# Recurrence relation advice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$t_n=5t_{n-1}+6t_{n-2}$

Is the characteristic equation of this correct? This is what I have:

$x$- 5$x$ -6=0

Is this correct?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: $n$ and $m$ are not the same, you are missing $t_{ }$ twice on the right, and the whole thing does not equal zero.  No, the characteristic equation is not correct.  You could also see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on formatting math here.

Comment: i understand how to do this fully. its just first time im seeing the other 0..it confused me a little..is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you mean $t_n=5t_{n-1}+6t_{n-2}$ you substitute in $t_n=ax^n$ and you will get $x^2=5x+6$  I don't know what the $=0$s are doing there.  If they are real, you have $t_n=0$ and are already done